# When using include(.) with conditions, how can I make sure I still get results from the first table, even if there are no matches on the included one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given this four models:

```
class Gradebook < < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gradebook_entries
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gradebook_entry_scores
end

class GradebookEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gradebook_entry_scores
end

class GradebookEntryScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gradebook_entry
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to get all the gradebook entries in a gradebook, including its associated gradebook_entry_score, but only the one that belongs to a particular user.

This is how I do it right now:

```
some_gradebook.gradebook_entries.includes(:gradebook_entry_scores).where(:gradebook_entry_scores => {:user_id => 50} )
```

And it works. Except that if there is no gradebook_entry_score for that user, then no gradebook_entry is returned.

```
    some_gradebook.gradebook_entries.includes(:gradebook_entry_scores).where(:gradebook_entry_scores => {:user_id => 50} )
=> []
```

I would like to always get all the gradebook_entries, regardless of whether there is a gradebook_entry_score for that user or not.

So, how can I make sure that I will get the results from the first table, even if there is no results from the included table?

EDIT 1:

A user may not have a gradebook_entry_score for a particular gradebook_entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the `.where(:gradebook_entry_scores => {:user_id => 50} )` is your problem here.

What if you start with the User in question, something like:

```
User.find_by_id(50).gradebooks.gradebook_entries.includes(:gradebook_entry_scores)
```

Comment: The correct query would be: User.find_by_id(50).gradebooks.find(1).gradebook_entries... at which point, it is the same as what I currently have